# Show that $A^3+4A^2+A=I_3$ for 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 2 & 1 \\ 2 & -4 & -4 \\ 2 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Show that $A^3+4A^2+A=I_3$

How would I go about doing this? The first step would suffice, but I'm having difficulty starting this off.

Comment: I should have specified; an identity matrix. Apologies.

Comment: The usual notation for the identity matrix is $I_3$, or simply $I$,

Comment: Why don't you just work out $A^3+4A^2+A$? You could start by finding $A^2$.

Comment: Hi Angina, I've just updated my question now. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: try to find out characteristics equation of A, then apply Cayley Hamilton's theorem.

Comment: The characteristic equation has the form $x^3+5x^2+\cdots=0$, so isn't directly applicable to this problem.

Comment: Every matrix A should satisfy its own minimal polynomial ( together with chateristic polynomial). So, if A satisfy some polynomial p(x), then p(x) should be in the form of a(x)m(x), where m(x) is minimal polynomial of A, and a(x) is some other polynomial.

Comment: If it's not still applicable, then I think there is some problem with this question given by op.

Comment: The OP will discover the problem if they ever get round to calculating $A^3+4A^2+A$.